# c# IEnumerable<Object> LINQ GroupBy - Merge 2 Groups

Tags: c#, arrays, linq, merge

I'm working on some LINQ GroupBy logic and I can't think how to elegantly and efficiently get this to work.

Basically, I have an `IEnumerable<Thing>` object (which is in the correct order!), where each Thing object has a RootId property. I want to group these objects on their RootId, which I have working:

```
IEnumerable<Thing> things; // Already has value assigned
var groups =
    (from thing in things
     group thing by thing.RootId into thingGroup
     select thingGroup.ToArray())
    .ToList();
```

groups is of type `List<Thing[]>`

Now here is the problem!

The above example is returning 5 items in the list. But, how would I merge 2 of the arrays into 1, leaving 4 items (again, keeping the order of course)??

The reason why is because 2 of the items has different RootId's but I want them to be treated the same i.e. grouped together.

I was going to concat and manipulate the arrays after the LINQ statement, but really it needs to be done as part of the group by/LINQ - any ideas?

Let me know if further examples or information is needed.

Thanks!

The merging criteria will be a manual process, so I was thinking of passing it into the groupby method like so:

```
var rootIdsToMerge = new List<Tuple<ID, ID>>
{
    new Tuple<ID, ID>(rootIdOne, rootIdTwo),
    new Tuple<ID, ID>(rootIdThree, rootIdFour)
};
```

So any group item with a RootId of rootIdOne will be merged with the group item with a RootId of rootIdTwo, and so on.

Comment: And what's the criteria of treating 2 RootId's the same? e.g. hardcoded values, some other property or?

Comment: It will be a manual process, so I was thinking of passing it into the method like so:
    `var rootIdsToMerge = new List<Tuple<ID, ID>>
    {
     new Tuple<ID, ID>(rootIdOne, rootIdTwo),
     new Tuple<ID, ID>(rootIdThree, rootIdFour)
    };`

Comment: Like what? Without more concrete example I don't see how we can answer. So we have `IEnumerable<Thing>`, what else?

Comment: Sorry Ivan, I'm trying to be as helpful as possible. Does my new "rootIdsToMerge" code help? But yea, these 2 objects is all that we have - I was hoping for some awesome LINQ query to achieve what I need :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are not using the grouping `Key`, you can associate the `Item2` from the mapping to `Item1` as a `RootId` key to group by:

```
var groups =
    (from thing in things
     group thing by rootIdsToMerge.FirstOrDefault(e => e.Item2 == thing.RootId)?.Item1 ?? thing.RootId
     into thingGroup
     select thingGroup.ToArray())
    .ToList();
```

Or in pre C#6 (no `.?` operator):

```
var groups =
    (from thing in things
     let mergeWith = rootIdsToMerge.FirstOrDefault(e => e.Item2 == thing.RootId)
     group thing by mergeWith != null ? mergeWith.Item1 : thing.RootId
     into thingGroup
     select thingGroup.ToArray())
    .ToList();
```

**Update:** If you just want to consolidate a list of `RootId`s, then you can use a combination of `Contains` and `First`:

```
List<ID> rootIdsToMerge = ...;
var groups =
    (from thing in things
     group thing by rootIdsToMerge.Contains(thing.RootId) ? rootIdsToMerge.First() : thing.RootId
     into thingGroup
     select thingGroup.ToArray())
    .ToList();
```

The variants with

```
List<List<ID>> rootIdsToMerge = ...;
```

are similar to the initial variant with tuples:

```
var groups =
    (from thing in things
     group thing by rootIdsToMerge.FirstOrDefault(ids => ids.Contains(thing.RootId))?.First() ?? thing.RootId
     into thingGroup
     select thingGroup.ToArray())
    .ToList();
```

or

```
var groups =
    (from thing in things
     let mergeList = rootIdsToMerge.FirstOrDefault(ids => ids.Contains(thing.RootId))
     group thing by mergeList != null ? mergeList.First() : thing.RootId
     into thingGroup
     select thingGroup.ToArray())
    .ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks Ivan, this is brilliant. I'm going to test now! :) Thinking about it, I guess rootIdsToMerge should be of type List<ID>, so that more than 2 groups can be merged. Is this doable? Sorry to add more work!

Comment: Do you mean `List<List<ID>>` or just `List<ID>`?

Comment: Depends on if you want more than one group of merged IDs - they way the query is written, you can repeat `Item1` and have differing `Item2`s to create larger groups, and also create multiple groups. Otherwise you would want to replace with `List<List<ID>>` and the query would need to change.

Comment: @IvanStoev Just List<ID> please.
Thanks NetMage I appreciate the input.

Comment: There you go :)

Comment: @IvanStoev you legend! :) Thank you very much. If it's not too much trouble (sorry, hehe) but I think you were right, List<List<ID>> makes more sense ;) One last update please? :)

Comment: Sure, that's just a variation of the version with tuples. Cheers.

Comment: Thank you, that's great.